# How to get the value of a textfield into another Textfield?

Tags: javascript, html, css

My Task:
Create 2 text areas and a button, assign the text in the 1st text area with the first verse of the song
When you click on the button, all vowels (aeiou) should be replaced by an a and the result should then be in the 2nd text field

My code:
 Drei Chinesen mit dem Kontrabass saßen auf der Straße und erzählten sich was. Da
kam die Polizei, fragt‚ Was ist denn das?‘ Drei Chinesen mit dem Kontrabass. 
 
Los

```
<script>

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    document.getElementById('button')
        .addEventListener('click', changeVowels);
    var durchlauf = 0;

    function changeVowels() {
        var vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'];
        var text = document.querySelector('textarea')
            .innerHTML;
        var ergebnis = text.replace(/[aeiou]/ig, vowels[durchlauf]);
        document.querySelector('textarea')
            .value = ergebnis;
        if (durchlauf < (vowels.length - 1)) {
            durchlauf++;
        } else {
            durchlauf = 0;
        }
    }
});
```

My question is, how do I get the value of the first textarea into to second. 
Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Do not try and use `.innerHTML` on a textarea. The way to get and set the value, is via `.value`

Comment: `document.getElementById("myTextarea").value`. Read from textarea 1, replace, write to textarea 2. But you have to give your textareas unique id's.

Comment: `querySelector` will always return the first found element only. If you want to select different textareas by tag name only, then you need to use `querySelectorAll`, and access them via index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this snippet:

```js
let durchlauf = 0;
const vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'];

function changeVowels() {
    let text = document.querySelector('#original').value;
    const ergebnis = text.replace(/[aeiou]/ig, vowels[durchlauf]);
    document.querySelector('#edit').innerText = ergebnis;
    if (durchlauf < (vowels.length - 1))
        durchlauf++;
    else durchlauf = 0;
}
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', changeVowels);
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="original">Drei Chinesen mit dem Kontrabass saßen auf der Straße und erzählten sich was. Da kam die Polizei, fragt‚ Was ist denn das?‘ Drei Chinesen mit dem Kontrabass.</textarea>

<textarea id="edit"></textarea>

<button id="button">Click</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for you Code. Could you show me how to put the Value from the textarea in another Textarea. Like the text should stay in the first Textarea and the edit text in the second Textarea.