# Change all vowels in a Songtext with a loop to "a"

Tags: javascript, html

I have to change all vowels in a Song with "a". I have to creat 2 textareas. In the first textarea should be the Original Song text. In the secon textarea should be the edited Songtext. For example: Original Text: I wish you a merry Christmas. Edited text: A wash yaa a marry Chistmas.

```
      <body>
    <textarea name="erstes" id="original" rows="5" cols="50">Drei Chinesen</textarea><br>
    <textarea name="zweites" id="edit" rows="5" cols="50"></textarea><br>
    <button type="button" onclick="pruefen()" name="button">Pruefen</button>

    <script>

      function preufen(){
        var eins = document.getElementById("erstes").value;
        var zwei = document.getElementById("zweites").value;
        var vokale = ['a','e','i','o','u']

        if ( eins != vokale ) {
          document.getElementById('zwei').innerText = document.getElementById('eins').value;
        }
      }

    </script>
  </body>
```

I've come this far. I hope you know what I mean and your opinion would help me a lot.

Comment: [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) the vowels in your string and set the new string as a value of the second text area

Comment: And what have you tried so far to solve this on your own? You already mentioned a _"loop"_ but there isn't one in your script. A search for "javascript replace text" should also give you enough resources to solve this problem.

Comment: Another question, using the same “Drei Chinesen mit dem Kontrabass” example text, asked two hours after https://stackoverflow.com/q/63825701/1427878 - am I really supposed to believe in coincidence here …?

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex for it, like, below one, it replaces all vowels with "a" in a given string.

```
const p = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. If the dog reacted, was it really lazy?';
const regex = /[aeiou]/gi;
console.log(p.replace(regex, 'a'));
```

output is:
"Tha qaack brawn fax jamps avar tha lazy dag. af tha dag raactad, was at raally lazy?"